# How would I have a method called if no other method has been called?

Tags: java

Im trying to set up a class that holds a certain value, and can then be used as it's default value. For example:

```
public class Account {
  private GUID;
  private balance;

  public Account(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
    this.GUID = new GUID();
  }

  public getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
  }
```

Then during usage I would to somehow have this work:

```
Account test = new Account(40);
System.out.println("Account balance: " + test);
```

That would return: `Account balance: 40`

Instead of having to write:

```
Account test = new Account(40);
System.out.println("Account balance: " + test.getBalance());
```

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: this particular: by implementing toString

Comment: ..and if you implement `toString()` I'd advise including the `Account balance:` part there too. It's a lot more descriptive than just the number.

Comment: but make sure you actually give a type to your variables. there is no way your current code will compile

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I am afraid you can't do that.

You can instead define a toString() method for that.
Because if you prinf the object directly (without any method), that apparently would print the address of that object, not the inside value of it's variables.

So yeah, you just can't do that.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This is false. If you output it directly with printf or similar, the runtime internally calls the `toString` method.

Comment: This was actually really useful, you understood what I was asking. Thanks and sorry for being so vague

Comment: Two meter, I second you. But that doesn't print a legit value for instance, in this case, the value of balance.

I don't think there is any point of printing the object value then as mentioned in the question by Michael, he wanted a method to be called from the class. A legit method.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this.

```
public class Account {
   private GUID guid;
   private int balannce;

 public Account(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
    this.guid = new GUID();
  }

  public getBalance() {
    return this.balance; 
  }      

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%03d", balance);
  }
}
```

Comment: please make sure your code is executable (at least compilable), indeed you took a copy from the question (which is limited). `private int balance`.. and you will have to return `String.valueOf(balance)` (or other formatting if applicable)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are asking, you need to override `toString()` method in your class, which is inherited from `Object` class (all classes in Java inherit from `Object` class).

You can add to the code of your method something like that:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.balance;
}
```

After overriding that method, when you call `System.out.println(test)`, you will see on the output the value assigned to the balance field from test object.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the way you have it written makes it look like 2.5 classes (or one class with 2 constructors) rather than a class with some methods like you want.

To get the class to work as is, change your class to look like this:

```
public class Account 
{
  private GUID; //Not sure if this needs a type or if GUID is the type!
  private double balance; //Added the double type, which holds a decimal

  public Account(int balance) //This is your constructor: no return type
  { 
    this.balance = balance;
    this.GUID = new GUID();
  }

  public double getBalance()  //Added return type for this method 
  {
    //Now it will return the number.
    return this.balance;
  }

  //Now to override the toString method for the class:
  public String toString()  //Notice this one returns String
  {
    return "Account balance: $" + this.balance.toString();
  }
}
```

So, as desired, you can now do `Account test = new Account(40);` which will create a new object based on your class, with the balance being 40.  You could extract just the number and store it in a variable for manipulation or adding a total by doing something like this: `double theBalance = test.getBalance();` and if you simply call toString() on your object, `test.toString();` it will return our fancy output of `Account balance: $40.0`

Note that a raw double can have many many decimal points of precision, so you will probably want to round these values in the toString function to make it pretty.  Since you made your balance variable a private variable, you will also need to create a "setter" function to change the balance after you create the object since you can only currently set it during the creation of the object.  Maybe you could rounde the value each time you update it so there is never any confusion about a customer's balance?

Hope this was able to help, leave a comment if you still have issues!  Java was my first language too, and it was a little crazy before I fully understood objects, but once you wrap your head around them... It's amazing how simple everything becomes.  It's good that you're learning them now